# Telegram бот не может отправить сообщение человеку

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Клиент вводит запрос, что он хочет, после чего этот запрос отправляется курьеру. После того как курьер его примет он может связаться с заказчиком.

Курьер не получает сообщение

````
# Встановлюємо токен вашого бота
TOKEN = "токен"

# Константа з ідентифікатором користувача кур'єра
COURIER_USER_ID = айди человека  # Замініть на реальний user_id кур'єра

# Функція для обробки команди /start
def start(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("Вітаю! Я бот для замовлення їжі. Введіть, що ви хочете замовити.")

# Функція для обробки повідомлень замовлення
def order_food(update, context):
    user_id = update.message.from_user.id
    food_order = update.message.text

    # Тут можна додати логіку для відправки замовлення кур'єру або збереження в базу даних

    update.message.reply_text(f"Ваше замовлення '{food_order}' отримано. Очікуйте кур'єра.")

# Функція для обробки відповідей кур'єра
def courier_reply(update, context):
    user_id = update.message.from_user.id

    # Перевіряємо, що користувач є кур'єром
    if user_id == COURIER_USER_ID:
        courier_message = update.message.text

        # Тут можна додати логіку для зв'язку замовника з кур'єром

        update.message.reply_text(f"Повідомлення від кур'єра: '{courier_message}'")
    else:
        update.message.reply_text("Ви не маєте права на доступ до цієї функції.")

def main():
    updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, order_food))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, courier_reply))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

def echo(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("Я отримав ваше повідомлення: " + update.message.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()```
````